# Filter date by month using angular.js filter

Tags: angularjs, date, filtering

I can filter data by date using the filter statement of angularjs but now I need to filter it only by month and year, there is a simple way to do it?

Here my code:

app.js

```
$scope.expenses = [{amount:100.00, date:"2013-12-20"}, {amount:100.00, date:"2013-12-20"}];
```

index.html

```
<input ng-model="expenseDate" type="date" value="dd-mm-yyyy" ng-required="true">            
<li ng-repeat="expense in expenses | filter:{date:expenseDate}">
    <span>{{expense.date)}}, {{expense.amount}} </span>
</li>
```

**Edited**

can't I do something like this?

```
<li ng-repeat="expense in MyOwnFilter(expenses) | filter:{date:expenseDate}">
    <span>{{expense.date)}}, {{expense.amount}} </span>
</li>
```

Or

```
<li ng-repeat="expense in MyOwnFunction() | filter:{date:expenseDate}">
    <span>{{expense.date)}}, {{expense.amount}} </span>
</li>
```

Comment: question is a bit too broad... as @dyelawn points out there are numerous ways to do it and determining best approach somewhat depends on how you want to use it. More context would help, demo would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

index.html

```
<input ng-model="expenseDate" type="date" value="dd-mm-yyyy" ng-required="true"> 
<ul class="row">
    <li ng-repeat="exp in MyOwnFilterFunction()">
        <span>{{CategoryName(exp.category_id)}}, {{exp.amount}} </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
$scope.expenses = [{amount:100.00, date:"2013-12-20"}, {amount:100.00, date:"2013-12-20"}];

$scope.MyOwnFilterFunction = function() {
    var data = []
    *** FILTER $escope.expenses USING $scope.expenseDate INTO data ***
    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are a lot of ways to do this that don't involve altering the data, the easiest/cleanest thing to do is probably to use three different values and inputs. Something like:

```
$scope.expenses.map(function (expense) {
    var date = expense.date.split('-');

    exepnse.day = date[0];
    expense.month = date[1];
    expense.year = date[2];

    return expense;
});
```

Then simply add input elements for date, year, and day and use multiple filters on your `ng-repeat`.

Comment: How can I use multiple filters with my unique `<input ng-model="expenseDate" type="date"...` ?

Comment: Well you shouldn't have one input, you should have 
`<input ng-model="expenseMonth"` and 
`<input ng-model="expenseYear"`, 

then use those inputs in the filter like:
`<li ng-repeat="expense in expenses | filter:{month:expenseMonth, year:expenseYear}"`.

Comment: I got it, but is it impossible to do it with only one input? I was asked to do it with only one